# cann't find taos.dll while using `make install` on windows

Tags: tdengine

I tried to build TDengine on window followed the instruction on [Build TDengine On Windows platform](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/develop/README.md#on-windows-platform):

using the command:

```
mkdir debug && cd debug
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" < x64 | x86 >
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles"
nmake
```

But i cann't find the taos.dll in ../windows/system32/ . In my opionion, taos.dll should under that directory. Does anyone know why that happen && how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a feature under Windows, you can move the `taos.dll` to `../windows/system32/`.

Answer (score 0):

Make script will not install any dll to system32 in TDengine, you should copy it with caution.